# Cannot acquire connection to Neo4j database

Tags: python, neo4j

I am trying to connect to my Neo4j graph database server from a new machine.  I can successfully connect from an older machine but do not wish to use the older one anymore.

I have reduced the problem to a simple script that returns an exception:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

auth = basic_auth("username","password")
session = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://remote.server:7687",auth=auth).session()

statement = """MATCH (a:Protein)
WHERE a.name={name}
RETURN a.Accession"""

tx = session.begin_transaction()
record = tx.run(statement,{'name':"ARCH_HUMAN"}).single()
print record['a.Accession']

session.close()
```

And the error message is:

```
File "Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    tx = session.begin_transaction()
File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 432, in begin_transaction
    self._connect()
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 269, in _connect
self._connection = self._acquirer(access_mode)
  File "/home/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/direct.py", line 52, in acquire
raise ServiceUnavailable("Cannot acquire connection to {!r}".format(self.address))
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Cannot acquire connection to Address(host='remote.server', port=7687)
```

Port 7687 is open (confirmed via `netstat -tulpn` and `iptables -L`), and neo4j is configured to listen to 0.0.0.0:7687. In addition, `.neo4j/known_hosts` contains an entry for host 0.0.0.0

What's strange is that I get a different error message (neo4j.exceptions.AuthError) if I break the authentication by using an incorrect password. So the connection *is* being made to check the password, but still I cannot connect with the correct auth.

What's going on?

Comment: @cybersam The issue with that one appears to be the specifying the port number, which is present here

Comment: I found if I downgraded from neo4j-driver v1.5.3 to v1.1.0b1 that the above script worked.  I will not add this as an answer to accept it yet, because I'd love an answer for the most up-to-date version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too had the same issue and turns out the driver was the issue.

I did some experiments and found out that the last driver that it works for is `neo4j-driver==v1.1.0` but the next version `neo4j-driver==v1.2.0` it stops working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncomment `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0` And check this

```
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687
# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474    
# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

Comment: I have the `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address` line commented, but `dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687` and `dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474`  Doesn't this do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the same. What do you have in log files?

Comment: Nothing about the attempted connection was in the log files